# What is the meaning of CELERY_TIMEZONE variable in the settings.py file of a Django project?

Tags: django, celery, celerybeat

I know that `USE_TZ=True` saves all the `datetime` objects in UTC in the database. In that case, when a task is scheduled to run at regular period of time (say every 2 days or every Monday) using django_celery_beat, why cant the scheduler directly take the values from the database in UTC and check `is_due` and run accordingly?

My basic question is what is the purpose of `CELERY_TIMEZONE` variable? What does it do?

Comment: I think now it is `timezone` instead of `CELERY_TIMEZONE`. http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#new-lowercase-settings

Comment: @tim ya..that upgrade is fine. But can I know what's the meaning of it? What does it do with respect to scheduling tasks?

Comment: I did get very clear explaination from others, based on my own understanding, enable it or not, does not really influence your codes or logic. (use `timezone=utc` as an example)It is an option to use `utc` time to different tasks in the queue. I think this only be helpful when your workers are wordwide, otherwise, it does not really different between using local tz or other tz.

Answer (score 1):

CELERY_TIMEZONE sets the timezone. This becomes important if our tasks are to be executed at a specific time.